# Fluent Migrator - Method is not supported by the connectionless processor

Tags: oracle, fluent-migrator

Never seen this error before and not sure what it's referring to. We just changed the instance of Oracle we are using and our existing code which was working for years and looks like this:

```
  [Migration(20171222164655)]
    public class _121_CleanupPaymentRouteTable : ForwardOnlyMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            if(Schema.Table("PaymentRoute").Exists())
            {
                Delete.Table("PaymentRoute");
            }
        }
    }
```

Is now throwing this error and I'm not sure why...

```
Unhandled exception. System.NotImplementedException: Method is not supported by the connectionless processor
   at FluentMigrator.Runner.Processors.ConnectionlessProcessor.TableExists(String schemaName, String tableName)
   at FluentMigrator.Builders.Schema.Table.SchemaTableQuery.Exists()
```

What is a connectionless Processor... and why are the extensions not functional when it is being used?

Tried updating the code to not use the built in fluentMigrator extensions and the error goes away... but I was not expecting the DB update to cause this... and I don't even understand why this is happening.